# Previous Radio buttons state not cleared objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton, radio-button

**What I want?**

Custom radio buttons, allowing a user to select a single option among multiple options

**Code**

```
 - (void)setupBtn{
        self.radioBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [self.radioBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(40,38,18,18)];
        [self.radioBtn setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.radioBtn setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button-select"]forState: UIControlStateSelected];
        [self.radioBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view2 addSubview:self.radioBtn];

    }
    - (IBAction)radioButtonTapped:(UIButton*)sender{
        if (self.radioBtn.isSelected ==  true) {
            [self.radioBtn setSelected:NO];
            self.view1.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
            [self.radioBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }else {
            [self.radioBtn setSelected:YES];
            self.view1.backgroundColor = [UACFCustomColors continentalLightBlueTransparent];
            [self.radioBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button-select"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try storing all your buttons in an array. When one gets tapped, loop through the array, and check if each button is selected. If the button is selected, set it to not be, then exit the loop. After the loop, set the button that was tapped (`sender`) to be selected.

Untested example code:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    self.radioBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.radioBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(40,38,20,20)];
    [self.radioBtn setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.radioBtn setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button-select"]forState: UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.radioBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.radioBtn setSelected:YES];
    [self.view2 addSubview:self.radioBtn];

    self.radioBtn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.radioBtn2 setFrame:CGRectMake(40,38,20,20)];
    [self.radioBtn2 setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.radioBtn2 setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button-select"]forState: UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.radioBtn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.radioBtn2 setSelected:NO];
    [self.view2 addSubview:self.radioBtn2];

    self.radioBtn3 = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.radioBtn3 setFrame:CGRectMake(40,38,20,20)];
    [self.radioBtn3 setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.radioBtn3 setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button-select"]forState: UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.radioBtn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.radioBtn3 setSelected:NO];
    [self.view2 addSubview:self.radioBtn3];
    self.buttonArray = @[self.radioBtn, self.radioBtn2, self.radioBtn3];

}

- (void) myButtonTapped:(UIButton*) sender {
    for(UIButton *btn in self.buttonArray) {
        // Only one button should be selected at a time, so once we find it,
        // set it to not be selected then break from the loop
        if(btn.isSelected){
            [btn setSelected:NO];
            break;
        }
    }
    // set the button that was tapped to be selected
    [sender setSelected:YES];
}
```

To send one button's text to another button's is fairly simple.

```
[btn2 setTitle:[btn1 titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: can't I achieve this by just adding single radioButton?